# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, html, sudoku

I'm trying to code a Sudoku generator in JavaScript and I think I did it. 
My problem is for visualizing the generated solution inside the input tags I use for the game. 
I put this function on the property onload of the body of my html page:

```
function begin() {
    var container=document.getElementById("container");
    var div;
    for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
        div=document.createElement("div");
        div.id=i;
        div.setAttribute("class", "square");
        for(var j=0;j<9;j++) {
            var square=document.createElement("input");
            square.setAttribute("type", "text");
            square.setAttribute("maxlength", "1");
            if(i%2==0) {
                square.setAttribute("class", "square1");
            }
            else {
                square.setAttribute("class", "square2");
            }
            div.appendChild(square);
        }
        container.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly fine, since it show 9 squares (the divs), each with 9 small squares inside(the inputs).

Now the last function is, to show the result is:

```
function showSudoku(sudoku, i) {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var cells = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var j=0; j<81; j++)
        cells[j].value = sudoku[j];
}
```

but I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

For some reason the variable container is not initialized with the element identified with the id `container`. Can anyone help me?

[EDIT]
Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sudoku</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                text-align: center;
            }
            #game {
                width: 21.2em;
                height: 21.15em;
                margin: auto;
                border: 2px solid #777777;
            }
            #container {
                width: 21.2em;
                height: 21.2;
                margin: auto;
            }
            .square {
                width: 6.94em;
                height: 6.94em;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid #A9A9A9

            }
            .square1 {
                height: 3em;
                width: 3em;
                background-color: white;
                border: 1px dashed #CBCBCB;
                color: black;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .square2 {
                height: 3em;
                width: 3em;
                background-color: #DDDDDD;
                border: 1px dashed #CBCBCB;
                color: black;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            input {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sudoku.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="begin()">
        <div id="levels">
            <label><input type="radio">Easy</label>
            <label><input type="radio">Medium</label>
            <label><input type="radio">Hard</label>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="newgame" onclick="newGame()">NEW GAME</button>
            <button id="solve">SOLVE</button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="game">
            <div id="container">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="time">
            <input id="currentTime" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The buttons and the inputs radio are still unused.

Comment: add your html code also to the question

Comment: In the head. It's right after the style tag.

Comment: Try to add your script after the <body> <script type="text/javascript" src="sudoku.js">

Comment: Still getting the same error. For some reason the var container stays null.

Comment: Where exactly is `showSudoku` getting called? The code is fine so it must be getting called  Can you create a working demo in a code snippet so we can see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

hey you are messing with tagname since you would not specify which input type you are wanting to append in the javascript. 
so you should have to go like this as follows:

```
    var nodeLists = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(node in nodeLists){   
     if(nodeLists[node].getAttribute('type') == "text"){
        //write code here as you want
       }
       else{
       } 
   }
```

Comment: How does this answer the problem if why `var container = document.getElementById("container");` is giving the error?

Comment: do you use this begin() javascript code in the head section or do not/

Comment: i think you should go with like this  way

Comment: Please update your answer to explain how to use the code you suggest, and how it fixes the error. At the moment this doesn't provide a clear answer to the question asked. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: window.onload =  function() {
    var container=document.getElementById("container");
    var div;
    for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
        div=document.createElement("div");
        div.id=i;
        div.setAttribute("class", "square");
        for(var j=0;j<9;j++) {
            var square=document.createElement("input");
            square.setAttribute("type", "text");
            square.setAttribute("maxlength", "1");
            if(i%2==0) {
                square.setAttribute("class", "square1");
            }
            else {
                ......

Comment: Please *update your **answer*** to include the code and also an explanation as to how this solves the OP's issue.

Comment: Hey You mentioned  in the post that your begin()  function  working properly.

Comment: You just have error in 2nd function as mentioned for this i provide info as           to     var nodeLists = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(node in nodeLists){   
     if(nodeLists[node].getAttribute('type') == "text"){
        //write code here as you want
       }
       else{
       } 
   }.

Comment: can you please in which function r u getting error rightnow and what is the error

Comment: 1. I am not the OP and 2. to meet Stack Overflow guidelines, you should provide a full and complete answer that will also benefit other users. So to make sure this answer isn't deleted for being off topic, please update it to explain **how** to use the code and **why** it will fix the OP's issue.

Comment: "*can you please in which function r u getting error rightnow and what is the error*" - the OP already has that exact information in their question.